# How to convert a string into an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, data-conversion

So I have obtained a string that looks like this:

```
string(138) "{"access_token":"#############","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}"
```

But I need to access only the `"#############"` (which is the access token) but in order to do that I need to convert this string to an array.
I have tried like this:

```
//this is the string
$access = $tokenNew["extra_details"];
//here I convert it to an array
$access_token = explode(' ', $access);
```

But by doing that I get something like this:

```
array(1) {
   [0] => string(138) "{"access_token ":"##########","token_type ":"Bearer ","expires_in ":3600}"
}
```

Any ideas why? Any help is welcomed! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string looks like a JSON. You could try the [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function on your string.

```
$array = json_decode($your_string, true);
echo $array['access_token'];
```

Comment: Info: The second parameter of `json_decode()`, forces the returned object to be converted into a associative array.

Comment: Thank you it is correct and it helped me understand how json_decode works! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

It's a json object, so you need to [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) it.

```
$json = json_decode($tokenNew["extra_details"], true);
$access_token = $json['access_token'];
```

Comment: Thank you this was the solution! Thank you for your time!